# How can clashes in msgget() or mq_open() be prevented?

Tags: posix, ipc, message-queue, sysv-ipc

As two calls (possibly in different processes) to either msgget() or mq_open() providing the same `key` argument give the caller access to the same message queue (which is usually intended), how can clashes be prevented?

I.e., as an application developer, how can I come up with a convention to generate `key`s for my message queue(s) that no other program on the system uses so as to avert unwanted interference?